# copy application jar to s3 using jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile, I have a `'Package'` stage followed by `'Copy Jar'` stage. I would want to copy the application jar that is getting built in the package stage to be used in the `'Copy JAR'` stage for copying to a s3 bucket. Right now I have the jar name hardcoded. I am familiar with `stash` and `unstash` but not sure if that might help here.

```
stage('Package') 
{
sh "mvn package"
stash includes: '**/target/*.jar', name: 'app'
}

stage('Copy JAR') 
{
unstash 'app'
sh "aws s3 cp $WORKSPACE/target/foo-bar.jar s3://my-bucket-name/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/"
}
```

I do not want to hardcode the `foo-bar.jar` here, instead use it from the unstash. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CLI supports wildcards - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/
Probably various ways, but this should do the trick:

```
sh("aws s3 cp $WORKSPACE/target/ s3://my-bucket-name/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include '*.jar'")
```

Comment: Hi I have a similar use case,
from my local i do this 
aws s3 cp "C:\Users\swagger-documentation\swagger" s3://my-bucket-dev --recursive. This commands uploads all my local files to s3 as expected. But I am building a Jenkins pipeline where objects needed to be uploaded into the s3 bucket must be taken from the github repository. 
am trying to do something like this 
sh(aws s3 cp "get location of swagger folder from git location" s3://my-bucket-dev --recursive)
I dont know how to specify to get from git location..

Comment: You could first clone/download the git repository and then its as per normal, files up loaded.